# Calculate the angle between a vector and a gravity pendulum

Tags: coordinate-systems, mathematical-physics, vectors

There is a physical device (sensor) which I can rotate. The device sends its X Y Z coordinates and a calculated acceleration vector in mg (mill mg).
For example:

X 116.0 Y 98.0 Z 151.0 MG 1031.0

X 117.0 Y 93.0 Z 152.0 MG 1042.0

X 117.0 Y 95.0 Z 151.0 MG 1044.0

This device should lay still on the table and its offset has to be 0 since the vector z is parallel to gravity pendulum and a central vector.

[image]

However, when I rotate the device, the central vector changes and the gravity vector stays. And what I have to calculate is this angle:

[image]

What I've been recommended to do so far is:

Let's take the data we receive:

X 116.0 Y 98.0 Z 151.0 MG 1031.0

X 117.0 Y 93.0 Z 152.0 MG 1042.0

X 117.0 Y 95.0 Z 151.0 MG 1044.0

1. Calculate average vector: ((116+117+117)/3 = 116,6; 95,3; 151,3)
2. Measure what value the device reports when lying stationary and flat. This will probably correspond to a vector along one of the axes of the sensor, whose magnitude corresponds to 1 g of acceleration.

In my case, when laying stationary and flat, the device reports (90; 90; 180), so my reference vector is (0, 0, 1).

3. Calculate direction: averageVector * 1/Sqrt(Dot(averageVector, averageVector))

Dot product of average vectors is: 45601,3.

SQRT of the dot product is: 213,54.

1 / sqrt is: 0,0047

direction = (116,6 * 0,0047; 95,3 * 0,0047; 151,3 * 0,0047) = (0,5463; 0,4464; 0,7087)

4. cosine = Dot(direction, referenceVector)
   cosine = 0,7087
5. Here we're using the fact that the dot product between two unit vectors gives the cosine of the angle between them. So we can use the inverse cosine function to turn that into an angle in radians, then rescale that to change the units into degrees.

However, when I receive a degree value, it says it is 44,8729. When in fact the device was lifted up for about 5 degrees or so, not 44.

If I change the average vector to (90, 90, 180) it should give me the degree error of 0, but instead I receive 35º value.

Could anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong? Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you sure the output of your sensor are the coordinates of a vector? The magnitude of the acceleration (last piece of data) is not the same as the magnitude of this supposed vector. Moreover, these numbers look more like angles to me. For instance: $(90, 90, 180)$ could mean that the acceleration vector makes angles of $90°$ with $x$ and $y$ axis of the sensor, and an angle of $180°$ with $z$ axis. This is a more likely interpretation, in my opinion.

Comment: Hi @Intelligentipauca! Thanks for your comment. Yes, I am sure that's a coordinate of a vector. Actually I solved the problem another way. To find the angle between the gravity pendulum (90,90,180) and a current vector (i.e. (116, 98, 151)) all I needed to do was (90 - 116, 90 - 98, 180 - 151). I solved it that way and it worked exactly as desired. And you're absolutely right. Those are the angles! :)

Comment: If those are the angles you cannot call it a vector, that's misleading. But then the solution to your problem is trivial: just compute the difference between $180°$ and the $z$ angle ($151°$ in your example) to find the rotation angle you need.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca, thank you for clarifying and structuring :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should your reference vector be $(1,1,2)$ instead of $(0,0,1)$

Then you'll get $\cos\theta = \frac{514.667}{\sqrt{6}\times 213.54}$ and the angle is about $10.3$ degrees.

Comment: Hi @JohnHunter! Thanks a lot for sharing your answer! Could you please elaborate, why my reference vector should be (1,1,2)?

Comment: Also, do you use this formula to find the angle?
cosϕ = ax⋅bx+ay⋅by+az•bz / sqrt(ax^2 + ay^2+az^2) • sqrt(bx^2 + by^2+bz^2)

Comment: Could you please be so kind to describe your steps more? Unfortunately, I wasn't even able to reproduce the 514.667. I get 2,4101 as the dot product of my direction (0,5463; 0,4464; 0,7087) and reference (1,1,2) vectors.

Comment: I also have tried just getting the 10.3º. So, when I divide 514,667 by sqrt(6)*213,54, I get 0,6008. If I convert it to degrees (0,6008 * pi / 180) I receive 0,0105 value.

Comment: The (1,1,2) is from the direction (90,90,180) all divided by 90.  The 2.4101 is ok and then we divide by the magnitude of each vector to get $cos\theta$.  Since the magnitude of your (0.5463  etc...) vector is 1,  $cos\theta = \frac{2.4101}{\sqrt 6}$ that's 0.9839, then inverse cos should give 10.3 degrees, best of luck with it...

Comment: Thank you a lot @JohnHunter, you have no idea how much your answer, time and help means to me!  Also, could you be so kind to tell me how you got 514,667, please?

Comment: It was your average vector 1. dotted with (1,1,2) i.e. 1 times 116.66 + 1 times 95.33 + 2 times  151.33.  Glad it helped, all the best.

Comment: Hi @JohnHunter! Thanks again for your answer! I've tried your solution and it worked. But now I have another question. When I tilt the device for about 5 degrees, the calculated angle is  approximately 10 degrees. When I turn the device upside down, the calculated angle is about 50 degrees, when in fact the central vector is still parallel to the gravity pendulum, so it should show ~0. When I put the device so that the angle between the central vector and a gravity pendulum is 90 degrees, it calculates 30 degrees. Do you perhaps know why this can happen?